# including dependencies in to docker image

Tags: docker

I am learning docker from linked in learning video class. Here trainer mentioned as below

> Include installer in your project . Five years from now the installer
> for version 0.18 of your project will not still be available. Include
> it. If you depend on a piece of software to build your image, check it
> into your image.

How can I check dependency into my image? My understanding is that if we build image software by giving commands like below.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.0
```

We already downloaded ubuntu software 14.0 version and created image. Why trainer is mentioning that version 14.0 is not possible to download
after 5 years down the line? Is my understanding right.

Thanks for your time in clarifying

Answer (score 0):

I'm having difficulty understanding what the LinkedIn teacher is trying to explain.

For images no longer available on DockerHub there is usually many years of pre-warnings before they're removed. For example [.Net Core 2.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-2-1-container-images-will-be-deleted-from-docker-hub/)

It's a no brainer that people (and companies) should invest to time to move away from unsecured legacy software. If an online teacher is saying pin Ubuntu 14 because you might need it in 2028, I consider that bad practice and not something a decent Engineer would ever aspire to do.

What your code is doing is asking for an Ubuntu image with the tag `14` so you can search [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/tags?page=1&name=14) to see the results. 14.04 has been recently pushed and scanned for log4js (a massive security vulnerability), coming back clean which is great. On the other hand 14.04.1 was pushed 7 years ago and is clearly not maintained.

One thing most companies do is to push images to ECR/Artifactory/DockerHub/etc so you could docker pull say `ubuntu:14.04` and then docker push it to your own container registry and you'll have it forever and ever amen. In this case you'd add your private registry to docker so it can discover the image or use a custom URL like `my-company-images@artifactory-company.com/ubuntu:14.04`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html